# Angular project template with ASP.NET Core: use with Bootstrap 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have installed Angular project template with ASP.NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

This is template for ASP.NET + Core + Angular, however, it uses Bootstrap 3. I want to move to Bootstrap 4.

What I tried:

- opened `package.json`
- changed `bootstrap` version

  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7", --> "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
- deleted `node_modules`
- run `npm install`

However, after I do this, my application never starts. It starts, but hangs forever - no error, no any page seen, loading forever. This template doesn't have webpack (I am not really sure I need it, never used it).

Comment: This issue related to bootstrap 4 dependencies jQuery or Popper, [Check bootstrap installation with Webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)